# Good HttpServletRequest wrapper for repeatable reads

Tags: java, http, servlets, request

Is there any good `HttpServletRequestWrapper` implementation that allows repeatable reads (multiple body reading etc.)? I can develop it by myself but I'd like to use some tested solution.